# Set PHP limits in Virtual Host FPM/FastCGI

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, fedora

I am trying to create individual setting of PHP (like memory_limit..) for Virtual Hosts But I dont know how could I do that.

I am using `Fedora 27 deamon httpd`, VHosts works good. When I put SetEnv PHPRC `/var/www/pokus.cz/php.ini` it doesnt work ( Yes I reloaded deamon).

I try just write `php_value memory_limit` `64M` to `VHost.conf` file but it prints error

`Invalid command "php_value"`

I Think that, it is because there is no `mod_php` in `Fedora 27 httpd`, but it uses `FPM/FastCGI`. How could I solve that, Thanks alot for any advise :)

Comment: you could define pools in php-fpm, and provide pool specific php tailoring in the pool config file.

Comment: Yes, it helps. I just create PHP-FPM pool and start VHost on it -> add socket parameter in VHost conf file. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set individual PHP parameters to your VHosts on server and there is PHP-FPM running on it, you could specify it by different FPM pools.

Just copy the default FPM pool called www (etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf) and edit:
name parameter (specify new socket name) and
listen parameter (specify new socket name, which will VHost run)
(You can edit the php parameters there, like memory_limit...)

Now you have to add this to your VHost conf file:

```
    <FilesMatch \.(php|phar)$>
     SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/yourchoosenname.sock|fcgi://localhost"
   </FilesMatch>
```

This will start your php scripts on new FPM pool for this specific VHost.

Dont forget to reload your web server (I use Apache, so systemctl reload httpd) and PHP-FPM.